# React-Router v5, cannot use history and link in the same project

Tags: react-router

In order to use history I have to use Router.

In order to use Link I have to use BrowserRouter.

Are history and Link just mutually exclusive then? How can I use both at the same time?

Comment: You can use history... wrap your component withRouter HOC or you can import useHistory hook, for Links it is obvious that you need to have router

Comment: @Freestyle09 turns out it's a problem with history v5, once downgraded to v4 everything is good. No need to use BrowserHistory

Answer (score 0):

Ok I resolved this.

2 things need to be done:

1. Use history v4 not v5
2. But history v4 API is different from v5, so make sure to read the correct docs